# Is it possible to generate the data for password fields when a user imports a schema into HCL OneTest Data from a database?

Tags: database, encryption, passwords, schema, password-encryption

When a user imports the schema or sample data set from the database, then can HCL OneTest Data generate the data for the password fields (Encrypted Data).

Answer (score 0):

HCL OneTest Data does not support the generation of encrypted data for the password fields.